# Invalid Syntax on $GITHUB_OUTPUT

Tags: github-actions

I have this code part on action file.

```
for repo in allRepos:
  allRepoNames.append(repo['name'])
  allRepoNamesList = ','.join(allRepoNames)
  print("::set-output name=allRepos::{0}".format(allRepoNamesList))
```

I want update this line print("::set-output name=allRepos::{0}".format(allRepoNamesList)) to use $GITHUB_OUTPUT, but I am getting the error - invalid syntax when I am using this code print("allRepos={0}".format(allRepoNamesList)) >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT

I've done other changes like: echo "groupId=$groupId" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT and this code is working, but I do not know how change this code print("::set-output name=allRepos::{0}".format(allRepoNamesList))

I really appreciate your help. Thanks!

Answer update: Thanks for the reply. Yeah it's Python, I've tried to do the following code, but I get an error

```
import os

output_file = os.getenv('GITHUB_OUTPUT')
for repo in allRepos:
  allRepoNames.append(repo['name'])
  allRepoNamesList = ','.join(allRepoNames)
  with open(output_file, "a") as myfile:
    myfile.write(f"allRepos={allRepoNamesList}")
```

In here is the error message:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gh1WO.png)

This my code:

```
name: "Get all repos"
description: "Get a full list of repositories in the organization"

inputs:
  organization:
    required: true
    type: string
  token:
    required: true
    type: string  
    
outputs:
  repos:
    description: Comma separated list of repositories
    value: ${{ steps.get-all-repos.outputs.allRepos }}
    
runs:
  using: "composite"
  steps:
    - id: get-all-repos
      name: Get all repositories
      shell: python
      run: |
        import os
        import urllib2
        import json
        repoResultsPerPage=100
        repoPageNumber=1
        gitHubOrganization='${{ inputs.organization }}'
        token='${{ inputs.token }}'
        allRepos = []
        allRepoNames = []
        allRepoNamesList = ''
        output_file = os.getenv('GITHUB_OUTPUT')
        # URL to send the request to
        url = '/api/v3/orgs/%s/repos?page=%s&per_page=%s' % (gitHubOrganization, repoPageNumber, repoResultsPerPage)
        # Custom headers to include in the request
        headers = {'content-type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'token %s' % (token)}
        # Create a Request object with the URL and headers
        req = urllib2.Request(url, headers=headers)
        # Send the request and store the response in a variable
        response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
        # Read the response data
        result = response.read()
        while result != '[]':
          print('PageNumber: %s' % (repoPageNumber))
          # Parse json
          json_data = json.loads(result)
          allRepos = allRepos + json_data
          repoPageNumber = repoPageNumber + 1
          url = 'api/v3/orgs/%s/repos?page=%s&per_page=%s' % (gitHubOrganization, repoPageNumber, repoResultsPerPage)
          req = urllib2.Request(url, headers=headers)
          response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
          result = response.read()
        for repo in allRepos:
          allRepoNames.append(repo['name'])
          allRepoNamesList = ','.join(allRepoNames)
          print("::set-output name=allRepos::{0}".format(allRepoNamesList))
```

Comment: It seems to be a python code, right? If yes, you can use the following syntax: `output_file = os.getenv('GITHUB_OUTPUT')` and then `with open(output_file, "a") as myfile: myfile.write(f"TEST={hello}")`. [Here is an example](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/new-output.py)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yeah it's Python, I've tried to do the following code, but I get an error

`imports
output_file = os.getenv('GITHUB_OUTPUT')
for repo in allRepos:
allRepoNames.append(repo['name'])
allRepoNamesList = ','.join(allRepoNames)
print("allRepos={0}".format(allRepoNamesList))
with open(output_file, "a") as myfile:
myfile.write(f"allRepos={allRepoNamesList}")`

Run import os
      myfile.write(f"allRepos={allRepoNamesList}")
                                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Could you update the question with this code snippet? It's a bit hard to see the indentation in comments :)

Comment: `allRepoNamesList` is a Dict, not a JSON, right? Did you try saving it as String just to check? I don't identify the origin of this invalid syntax.

Comment: Yes, the allRepoNamesList data like: `allRepos=repo1,repo2,repo3` and I tried convert to string `allRepoOutPut = str(allRepoNamesList)`, but I got the same error about the syntax on `myfile.write(f"allRepos={allRepoNamesList}")`

Comment: I've made a test [here](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/workflow-tester85.yml) with your implementation and [the output](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/actions/runs/5925721083/job/16065684700) seems to be as expected. Could you check what may be different here?

Comment: I was checking, but I do not see where the code is wrong to return the output data with GITHUB_OUTPUT. I added all my code in the question, I see your sample is different on some "uses", Then I think may be that parat where I am working with other options. Thank you for you time.

Comment: Using the same workflow I shared above, calling [this script](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/scripts/list-output2.py) instead of the other one should work (I didn't have `token` to test).